# Is computer device ID different from BitLocker recovery key identifier ID?

Tags: windows-11, bitlocker

I just saved a copy of my BitLocker Drive Encryption recovery key, which comes with the following warning: "To verify that this is the correct recovery key, compare the start of the following identifier with the identifier value displayed on your PC. Identifier: XXX"

However, when I check 'about your PC' setting on my windows 11 enterprise system, it gives me different device ID - in the same format i.e. same length, hyphens in the same places, but different letters and numbers.

From the previously asked questions on superuser, I understand that identifier ID is something I need to check when I am recovering a BitLocker enabled drive. However, my question is that is device ID in 'about your PC' supposed to be different to identifier ID when you have your BitLocker recover key? If so, then does device ID refer to the machine while identifier ID refers to the hard drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BitLocker identifier refers to a specific *key protector* (basically the recovery key itself) on a specific BitLocker volume. It has no association with the physical HDD, nor with your account, nor with the computer in general – every time a new recovery key is generated, it gets a new random UUID.

So you could have a bunch of recovery keys saved (or printed out), e.g. after several reinstalls/re-encryptions of the same disk, and the UUIDs let you find the correct key that the computer needs right now (without trying all of them).